# Stack pointer in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, stack, stack-pointer, rl78

I have a C exercise call a function from assembly. "Calculate perimeter of a triangle".

```
int a = 3, b = 4, c =5;
int Calculate_triangle(int a, int b, int c);
```

I have a code of Assembly here

```
PUSH HL
PUSH AX
MOVW AX, [HL]
ADDW AX, [HL+8]
ADDW AX, [HL+10]
POP  AX
POP  HL
RET
END
```

I know "a" will put in [HL]. But I have no idea why the b store in [HL+8].
Could anyone help me
*I'm using RL78G14 renesas and cubesuit+ compiler

Comment: Missing code. Also note that ADDW is not MOVW.

Comment: Is the C code supposed to call the assembly code you show? How does the C code actually call that assembly code? What calling convention is used? What C compiler and what assembler are you using?

Comment: Also, if the returned value is supposed to be in `AX` then you should not `push ax` and definitely not `pop ax`.

Comment: Doesn't look like x86, maybe RL78?

Comment: @m0skit0 i think it MOVW "a" into AX, then "a" plus "b" by using ADDW AX, [HL+8]. I don't know why it is HL + 8

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude See my edit. the return value is on BC register.

Comment: That's not x86; x86 doesn't have a `HL` register.  Is it 8080?

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry. I don't know. the hardware I'm using is RL78G14 Re nesas. and cubesuie plus compiler

Comment: @PeterCordes 8080 wouldn't be able to offset HL like that, that narrowed down the list a lot

Comment: You should be able to disassemble the C part calling your assembly function. Then you might see why `b` is stored at `HL+8`.